# How can I make an object "solid"?

Tags: valve, hammer

In Valve's software Hammer (Counter-Strike Global Offensive SDK Hammer software, for reference), I have created several props that I plan to have players jump on. However, players pass right through this prop.

How can I make it so that a prop is solid, and so that players can't walk right through the prop? Also, the prop is a static prop.

Comment: We don't get a lot of questions about hammer, or modding on this website, so I don't know if you'll get an answer. However, you might find an answer in the official [Valve Hammer Wiki](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Category:Hammer).

Comment: @JohnMcDonald Thanks for the advice. :) I actually already checked there, and found no answer :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I downloaded Hammer to try this out. Looks like this is how you do it:

1. With the Selection tool active, double click the object you want to make solid.
2. Set its class to `prop_static`
3. Select Collisions from the property list
4. To the right of the property list, change the value in the drop down from `Not Solid` to either `Use Bounding Box` or `Use VPhysics`

[image]
(The image numbers are actually -1 from the steps listed, oops)

Comment: Does `VPhysics` mean the object has that horrible warping effect in multiplayer?

Comment: No idea. But, as far as I know, `VPhysics` means it uses the mesh for collisions instead of the bounding box. `VPhysics` was the setting that most of the objects like crates/barrels were using in one of the standard maps I was viewing. Further, I think `prop_static` means it's not going anywhere, so I don't think there would be any warping.

Answer (score -3):

Idk if this is helpful but changing it to prop_physics_multiplayer might be useful

Comment: If you don't know if your answer is helpful, please don't post it.

Comment: Improving this answer might just be a matter of editing it to explain in a bit more detail why you think `prop_physics_multiplayer` could be useful, such as excerpting the relevant documentation or describing how you've used it yourself. It's OK to post speculative answers, but they should be backed up with some reasoning or explanation so we're not just throwing eggs at a wall ("Try this setting ... try that setting ... maybe this one?"